# How to get aligment of text?

Tags: python, python-docx

I use `ooxml.doc.Text`, and need to know that text is in a center, left, or in right.
In `Text` i have only these functions/values: `'parent', 'ppr', 'reset', 'rpr', 'text', 'value'`, in this class not have `aligment` variable.
How I can get that?

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far

Comment: @RachelGallen I not tried anything. I need to know how to get alignment.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to go directly into the xml for that?

```
d = Document()
alignment = d.paragraphs[0].paragraph_format.alignment
print(alignment)
```

Otherwise, I don't think, that you'll find that information in .Text I think. I might be wrong, but I think, that you define the alignment on the paragraph-level.